# Date command to output null/nothing when supplied variable has empty value

Tags: date

How would a `date` command output null/nothing when the variable supplied has no/null value. I know `if else` statement can do this, but I kinda think it's not the proper way. Is there a decent command or alterations to the `date` command to do this?

E.g.

```
myDay=""
bDay=`date -d "$myDay"`
echo "$bDay" // this should have no output
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
bDay=${myDay:+$(date -d "$myday")}
```

or:

```
if [ -n "$myDay" ]; then
  bDay=$(date -d "$myDay")
else
  bDay=
fi
```

or:

```
bDay=$([ -z "$myDay" ] || date -d "$myDay")
```

or (with an error message if `$myDay` is empty):

```
bDay=$(date -d "${myDay:?no date supplied}")
```

Note that `echo` (except for `csh`'s `echo`) always outputs at least a newline character (unless you use `-n` or `\c` depending on the `echo` implementation), even when not passed any argument, so you'd also need:

```
[ -z "$bDay" ] || echo "$bDay"
```

for not outputting anything when `$bDay` is empty.

Comment: I'm using your first suggestion. Thanks a lot! +1